# How to insert an empty string into list if there are not 3 strings between matches

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list

How to insert an empty string to list if there are not 3 strings between matches.
I want to find out if every 4th element is some kind of number (i.e. 12.1234., 1.12.13, etc.) and if not I want to insert an empty string before the second number so there are always 3 strings between each match.

```
  list =  ['1.1', 'ab','ac','','1.2','dd','','1.3','cb','dd','', '1.4', 'de','']
  wanted_list =['1.1', 'ab','ac','','1.2','dd','','', '1.3','cb','dd','', '1.4', 'de','','']
```

This is what Ii got so far, but the loop never ends and inserts way to many empty strings at the end (not just when there are not 3 strings between the matches).

```
list =  ['1.1', 'ab','ac','','1.2','dd','','1.3','cb','dd','', '1.4', 'de','']
start_rx = re.compile('|'.join(
    ['\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d', '\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\.', '\d\d\.\d\d\d\d', '\d\.\d\.\d\.', '\d\.\d\.\d\.\d\d\.',
     '\d\.\d\.\d\.\d\d\d\.', 'A\d\d\d\d', '^\d\.', '^\d\.\d', '^\d\.\d\.\d', '^\d\.\d\.\d\d', '\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d', '\d.\d']))
count = 1
for i, line in enumerate(list):
    count += 4
    if re.match(start_rx, line):
        pass
    else:
        i=count
        list.insert(i, '')
        print (list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach groups the list into nested lists of digit/decimal values and others and iterates over the non-digit/decimal groups (odd indexed groups) to determine whether they contain the required 3 elements and fill with empty strings if needed. You could use regex in the `isfloat()` function below in line with your initial attempt but it seemed easier just to test for digits after removing decimals.

```
from itertools import groupby

def isfloat(s):
    return s.replace('.','').isdigit()

items =  ['1.1', 'ab','ac','','1.2','dd','','1.3','cb','dd','', '1.4', 'de','']
groups = [list(g) for _,g in groupby(items, key=isfloat)]
for group in groups[1::2]:
    group += [''] * (3 - len(group))

result = [item for group in groups for item in group]
print(result)
# OUTPUT
# ['1.1', 'ab', 'ac', '', '1.2', 'dd', '', '', '1.3', 'cb', 'dd', '', '1.4', 'de', '', '']
```